# Restore Windows 8.1 bootloader after installing Ubuntu on a separate HDD

Tags: windows, bootloader, restore

I have Windows 8 installed on a separate HDD and Ubuntu on a separate HDD as well.

So I re-installed Ubuntu 14.14 because my previous installation was corrupted. Now when I boot my computer there is no option for windows. I can't even access the HDD because for some reason it's not mounting or Ubuntu isn't recognizing it.

I really need to recover that HDD because I have a lot of my homework on it.

Edit: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11052228/ The boot information

What other information do you need to help me fix this?

Comment: Instead of editing the title to say "Solved", accept the answer that solved it.  We have a specific system for that, and this isn't a 'forum' where you have to mark it as 'solved' by changing the title.

Comment: My bad I didn't see that faint check mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If everything is OK, you Windows partition should be recognized at GRUB menu after this command.

Comment: Alright, I'm about to restart, I'll tell you how it goes...

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: You are always welcome, I am happy it worked! ;)